# Return image from React.js function on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to React.js and I am trying to create SlideShow....

At first when page loades one image will be loaded (first one in array), then when user clicks left on `tag` `<a>` the function `slides()` should **return path** from *global variable*.
Images are imported right and they are in array... whenever page loads only first picture is visible and it's impossible to change between images.

What can I do so I can return *path* to `<img>` tag so right image would appear?

```
import bg1 from "../images/bg1.jpg";
import bg2 from "../images/bg2.jpg";
import bg3 from "../images/bg3.jpg";

global.images = [
    bg1, bg2, bg3
];
```

```
function slides(n) {
    return(
        global.images[n]
    );
}
```

```
<div className="slideShow">
   <img alt="Image" src={slides(0)} className="w-100 h-100"/>
   <a href="" className="prev" onClick={slides(1)}>&#10094;</a>
   <a href="" className="next" onClick={slides(2)}>&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way of tracking the active slide number after you can just change the image src

```
let currentSlide = 0;

let images = ["src1", "src2", "src3"];

function changeSlide(amount) {
  currentSlide += amount;

  currentSlide = currentSlide < 0 ? images.length : currentSlide;

  currentSlide = currentSlide > images.length ? images.length : currentSlide;

  let slideShow = document.getElementById("image");

  slideShow.src = images[currentSlide];
}

changeSlide(1);

changeSlide(-1);
```